# Excel to Access date error in formatting

Tags: excel, date, ms-access, append, date-formatting

I am having an issue with a program. The macro in Access imports an Excel file, then it appends an already created table with the imported data, and runs a check after to make sure that the table was appended correctly.

I have tried for hours to figure out why my imported tables are not being appended. I know that this is a formatting issue. There are six columns in my Excel table. The first three columns have Text Data Type. The fourth has Number Data Type. These are fine since the field properties match exactly for the imported table and the already existing table.

So my issue is with the last two columns. The last two columns in the existing table in Access have Date/Time Data Type. The format of these columns as shown in Field Properties is m/d/yy;@ (I'm not sure what this means and an explanation of this might be helpful)
The imported table has Date/Time Data Type with format m/d/yyyy. I have tried changing the format in Excel to m/d/yy and m/d/yy;@. Both of which got the format to show correctly in Excel, just as it does in Access for the correct table. But when I import it does not keep this formatting.

The check does not register the rows with new dates and the table does not get appended. I am looking for an easy fix in Excel to change my data's formatting as there are 17 separate macros that I have to run each month.

Comment: Hm, I have no idea what `m/d/yy;@` is. I don't see any noticeable difference when testing dates in Excel.

Comment: `Dates` in both Excel and Access are represented internally by a Long Integer value (with an optional decimal part, for time of day). The format of the date should be immaterial and settable in either Excel or Access. It's possible when importing data from Excel to Access that the date column format is transferred also, but it still should be stored as a `Date` (i.e. integer value) in Access.

Comment: The `@` in the format string in this case really isn't used. It exists as a "Text Placeholder" (see [this good reference](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=121:custom-number-formats-date-a-time-formats-in-excel-a-vba-numberformat-property&catid=79&Itemid=475) ).